# How can I get new changes after restarting Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm using Windows, but on Virtual Box I have Linux OS for testing Docker. So I want to restart my VM to get changes which will be applied only after restarting it. 
As said documentation:

> If testing on a virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the
>   virtual machine for changes to take effect.

1) If I close VM saving the state without taking snapshot:

[image]

and re-running it like:

[image]

I don't see any changes after restarting in Linux terminal.

2) If I reset:

[image]

and my settings are like (or ticking Live CD/DVD):
[image]

All changes will be reset and nothing will be applied.

3) If I take a snapshot and restore it:

[image]

Then I see only the same actions as I have written before but nothing new will be applied.

Can I somehow restart Virtual Box to get new changes that will be applied in addtition to my actions?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to create a snapshot, then restart to finalize changes, then restore from the snapshot? Going back to the snapshot will undo the changes from the restart. If you're already powering it off, it's obvious uptime doesn't matter, so why do you need to restore from the snapshot?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What documentation says "_If testing on a virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the virtual machine for changes to take effect._"?

Comment: udlp, I want to get new changes which will be applied after restarting Virtual Box. Now if I'm trying to reboot my VM using options above I don't get new changes only actions which I've written before.

Comment: "_Restart VirtualBox (Hypervisor)_" and "_Restart VM (Linux)_" are two very separate things... did you install a VirtualBox addon? It's hard to believe that installing a package (including docker) in the VM would require anything more than a normal reboot, and certainly nothing special for being in a VM.

Comment: Attie, I need to get new changes (in my case I need to get user in group) as said Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) after rebooting VM. I tried to log out and then log back, but I don't get new changes as well.

Comment: Adding yourself to a user group doesn't (shouldn't) require a reboot, but you will need a new session (i.e: logout / login)... Did you run `usermod -aG docker $USER` successfully? What is the output of `id`? What is the output of `grep '^docker:' < /etc/group`?

Comment: Yes, I run successfully the command `usermod -aG docker $USER`, but if I run then  `groups` I see everything like: `mint adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare` but not `docker` as group which supposed to be there.

Comment: Neither close or reset the machine but rather trigger a normal reboot from within the VM if you have to. Consider using [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) and make sure you're not using a LiveCD environment as suggest by @Evengard in his answer.

Comment: @Attie,output of `grep '^docker:' < /etc/group` is `docker:x:998:mint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting in this context is needed to apply some changes in underlying file system and configuration (i.e. loading a different kernel), which may be impossible wihout the restart as they are being used by the system. The restart makes sure that all the resources are freed and that the system can load updated ones without conflicts with previous ones.

When you either save the machine state or take a snapshot, you "freeze" your filesystem and configuration completely. So, a restart after restoring from the machine state or snapshot won't do what you are attempting to - it won't load new files and configurations, because you froze them.

It seems that you are using a LiveCD which doesn't save the data onto the HDD (the VDI file). Each "normal" reboot is making the system clean again, and snapshots won't help because you will be entering the "freeze" pitfall as described above.

The only solution you have here is to actually install a system on the Virtual Machine HDD (the VDI file) and only then attempting whatever you are trying to accomplish. Usually the same LiveCD have an option to install it. That may be the only one course of action you might have here.

Comment: He could run [Docker Dektop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/). Why do you assume he's running a LiveCD?

Comment: you're right, Seth, I could run Docker Desktop for Win. But I'm testing it on Linux. So my question relates more to Linux OS now. Anyway thanks for this link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Evengard. Can you a bit clarify, what do you mean with VDI file as HDD? As you can see my third screen I have Linux Mint.vdi, is it not what I need in my case, right? This file will be in settings after creating new VM.

Comment: When you're using a LiveCD, even though you have an HDD, it doesn't get used. That's the purpose of the LiveCD, to run a system without making changes to the HDDs of the system. So even though you have it it doesn't get used. You can use it only after you install the system to it, so the system is not LiveCD-typed after that.

Comment: Also, I assumed a LiveCD was used because of the Screenshot of the configuration with a Linux Mint CD, which by default probably gets booted into a LiveCD system, and the description of the symptoms in 2).

Answer (score 0):

As additional information to the main answer. I simply forgot to run manually on desktop installer for *Mint* (because system is working without it as well). The same thing is working automatically for Ubuntu after running, but for Mint - no.

[image]

After running this installer, I also solved the error: `No bootable medium found! System halted.`

which I received after restart OS.
And step by step re-configured all for Mint system thanks to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPDNnpsdteU).